# SSFIVAE: Why do Ryu's standing and jumping EX.Tatsu do different damage in combos?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv

Why does Ryu's standing EX.Tatsu -> Ultra 1 (in corner) do more damage then Ryu's jumping EX.Tatsu -> Ultra 1 (in corner)?

Here is what I found:

standing EX.Tatsu -> Ultra 1

- EX.Tatsu without Ultra does 160 damage in 5 hits.
- whole combo does 458 damage

jumping EX.Tatsu -> Ultra 1

- jumping EX.Tatsu without Ulta does 200 damage in 5 hits.
- whole combo des 362 damage

Theoretically the jumping Tatsu has more base damage and it should be better then the standing one especially in combos. It cannot depend on damage reduction on hit as both Tatsu hit 5 times.

Comment: +1 for research (although I'm very far from having an inkling of an answer)

Comment: This may sound an obvious question, but does the Ultra hit with full hits on the second case?

Comment: Hum, just tested on the iPhone. The iPhone implementation of Street Fighter IV might have different attack data, but both EX Tatsus did 200 damage, and the whole combo did 518 damage.

Comment: Do you have SSF4 or SSF4AE?

Comment: @Wilerson: Your are right -.-. Standing = 13 Hit Combo, Jumping = 9 Hit combo. So it seems only half the Ulta hits. Formulate an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @ayckoster: OK. Searching for an explanation on juggling potential, I found the juggling data for Ultra 1 and understood the entire issue. It's nice when answering to a question makes you learn more about what you're answering. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ultra must not be hitting for all 8 hits.

This possibly may be because the hits in jumping EX Tatsu count as juggle hits and there's a limit on how many hits can juggle in a combo. Metsu Hadouken has a juggling potential of 8, of which 4 are used for the last 4 hits on the jumping EX Tatsu, and the other 4 are used for the first 4 hits of the Ultra. That's why the last 4 hits whiff.

Standing EX Tatsu must not juggle the opponent until it launches them on the last hit. So the juggle counter only starts on the first hit of the Ultra.

[This link](http://sonichurricane.com/?p=618) has an explanation of juggling as it works on the SF4 engine.

Answer (score 1):

This possibly has to do with the way SF4 [scales damage](http://www.eventhubs.com/guides/2009/may/09/how-combo-and-damage-scaling-works-street-fighter-iv/) for combos.

There are two types of damage scaling in the first SF4, the first is the number of hits in the combo.  Since both combos do the same number of hits, this doesn't matter.

The second type of scaling has to do with the health of the enemy fighter.  I can't seem to find numbers yet for SSF4AE, but it would make sense as your second jumping EX Tatsu takes off more health, which may cause the ultra to be scaled due to the enemy having lower health.  136 damage difference in the two ultras seems to be a lot though, for health based scaling purposes.

A second possibility:

It could be just a bug, perhaps for jumping Tatsu, it counts the # of combo hits differently for purposes of comboing.  162 damage is approximately 40% 372, which means its scaled to 40% (if the ultra was considered to be the 7th hit rather than the 3rd hit in the first case).  This makes some sense as ultras are normally penalized at a 2 hit rate.  So a standing tatsu->ultra penalizes the ultra at a rate of 80%, but if a jumping tatsu counted as 5 hits instead of 1, then the ultra will be penalized as the 7th hit, which scales the damage down to 40%.